Selenium + Python: проблема с checkbox
Есть задача протестировать некоторый фронтенд. Конкретно - проверить статусы чекбоксов - отмечены они или нет. Однако при проверке статуса для отмеченных чекбоков все время получаю статус False, хотя должно быть True. Таким образом, статус всегда False, отмечен чекбокс или нет.
Фрагменты кода страницы c чекбоксами привела на скриншотах.
чекбокс checked

чекбокс unchecked

Статус проверяю методом .is_selected():
    element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div/div[2]')
    assert element.is_selected() == 'True'

В итоге ошибка
test_front_selenium.py:54 (test_case_1)
False != 'True'

Expected :'True'
Actual   :False

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему. Это мой первый вопрос здесь, поэтому если информации недостаточно, предоставлю.
1:
Вывела на печать element:
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div/div[2]')
    print(element)

вот что печатается в консоли:
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d181c1b98d16901cda5bbd6c1009df3b", element="483ee4da-a0e9-4da8-a552-d9674a5d7c02")>

Отсюда вопрос: возможно, метод нельзя применить к WebElement? Как мне получить именно экземпляр чекбокса, если это возможно?

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

is_selected - это наверное не то что вы думаете

из любопытства, я пробовала подставлять в выражение "assert element._______ == 'True' " все методы: .is_displayed(), .is_enabled(), .accessible_name и прочие, чтобы понять, что же нужно. Потом читала про эти методы - именно .is_selected() подходит по описанию на то, что мне нужно проверить.
